# Instantiate Game Object floating in air

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a tower defense game in Unity 3D C#. The goal is for players to place objects in a grid (grid code below).  I'm having trouble getting the "Corner" object to get placed on the ground, it's just appearing anywhere in the Y axis that I click.  I'm confused because I'm using the same exact script for a different item and it's working fine (I just changed out the words "wall" for "corner").  The only difference between the items is that one is a straight line and one is an L shape (I did this through making two cubes, combining them, and putting them as a child Empty game object called "corner").  Any ideas?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Grid : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float size = 1f;

    public Vector3 GetNearestPointOnGrid(Vector3 position)
    {
        position -= transform.position;

        int xCount = Mathf.RoundToInt(position.x / size);
        int yCount = Mathf.RoundToInt(position.y / size);
        int zCount = Mathf.RoundToInt(position.z / size);

        Vector3 result = new Vector3(
            (float)xCount * size,
            (float)yCount * size,
            (float)zCount * size);

        result += transform.position;

        return result;
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
        for (float x = 0; x < 40; x += size)
        {
            for (float z = 0; z < 40; z += size)
            {
                var point = GetNearestPointOnGrid(new Vector3(x, 0f, z));
                Gizmos.DrawSphere(point, 0.1f);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

CornerPlacer:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CornerPlacer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Grid grid;
    public GameObject corner;
    public bool placeCornerMode;

    private void Awake()
    {
        grid = FindObjectOfType<Grid>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (placeCornerMode)
        {
            GetItemsCorner();
        }
    }
    void GetItemsCorner()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hitInfo;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
            {
                PlaceCornerNear(hitInfo.point);
                placeCornerMode = false;
            }
        }
    }
    private void PlaceCornerNear(Vector3 clickPoint)
    {
        var finalPosition = grid.GetNearestPointOnGrid(clickPoint);
        Instantiate(corner, finalPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    }
    public void CornerModeOn()
    {
        placeCornerMode = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: compare the pivot point and child positions of both prefabs you are talking about .. are the identical or is your `Corner` pivot maybe different, meaning your child objects have an unexpected offset from `Corner`?

Comment: Btw if both components do exactly the same just a variable is called differently ... why not simply using the same component twice and only reference something else in the `corner` field?

Comment: Solved with the unexpected offset, thank you! And your second question is a good one, I'm new to this and just figuring things out